# How to insert a separate record for each list element

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of trackid. I want to add history record for each trackid in my table.
For example: trackid '37782x', 'y78929', '87882s', '989938-01' (they can be 200-300). Any way to add that through a single script?

```
Insert into notes
  (  type,
     trackID,
     Note,
     EntryDate,
     EntryID
  ) Values (
            1, 
            <MY trackid HERE>,
            'SOME History text HERE.',
            getDate(),
            0
        )
```

Comment: Since T-SQL has no lists, what does `I have a list of trackid.` mean? In what language? You can create an `INSERT` that inserts multiple rows by hand, but if you want to go from that list to the `INSERT` statement you'll have provide more information. Is it a table variable or TVF? You can use `INSERT ...FROM @thatTable t`. Is this a client-side list? There are ways to generate multi-value INSERTs in various languages

Answer (score 0):

[link to official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
Insert into notes
  (  type,
     trackID,
     Note,
     EntryDate,
     EntryID
  ) 
Values
    (1, <MY trackid 1>,'SOME History text HERE.',getDate(),0),
    (1, <MY trackid 2>,'SOME History text HERE.',getDate(),0)
;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).